# CanCanCan Authorize creation of a child record based on its parent's attributes

Tags: cancancan

I'm currently trying to set up a CanCanCan authorization on a child model based on a parent models attributes, but I can't seem to get it to work. I need to to something like the following:

```
can(:create, Bid) { |b| b.request.status == :open }
```

So in my situation, a Request can have many bids, but you should only be able to create bids when the request is still open for bidding.

The problem is the instance of a Bid will always have a request of `nil`.

I noticed authorization runs before the controller does, so it uses my `bid_params` before I run `@bid = @request.bids.build(bid_params)` in the controller.

I have tried using `load_and_authorize_resource :bid, through: :request` but that doesn't seem to help.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to do it "manually" before using `load_and_authorize_resource`.

```
def create
  @bid  = @request.bid.find(params[:id])
  authorize! :create, @bid
end
```

your ability can be rewritten in a simpler way as

```
can :create, Bid, request: { status: :open }
```

when this works, also using

```
load_and_authorize_resource :request
load_and_authorize_resource through: :request
```

should work and you can remove your "manual" call to `authorize!`

Comment: I could help you but I'd need more details then "for some reason" :)